# Can parallel_bulk compete with curl command for insert in ES?

Tags: python, performance, elasticsearch

I got some documents (size about `300o/doc`) that I'd like to insert in my ES index using the python lib, I got huge time difference between the code and using `curl` it's obvious that it's normal, but I'd like to know if time can be improved (compared to the ratio of time)

1. `curl` option takes about **20sec** to insert and whole time **10sec** (for printing ES result but after 20sec data is inserted)

   ```
   curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST 
           "localhost:9200/contentindex/doc/_bulk?" --data-binary @superfile.bulk.json
   ```
2. With `python` option, I reached **1min20** as minimum, using the setting `10000/16/16` (`chunk/thread/queue`)

   ```
   import codecs
   from collections import deque
   from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
   from elasticsearch.helpers import parallel_bulk

   es = Elasticsearch()

   def insert_data(filename, indexname):
       with codecs.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as fic:
           for line in fic:        
               json_line = {}
               json_line["data1"] = "random_foo_bar1"
               json_line["data2"] = "random_foo_bar2"
               # more fields ...        
               yield {
                   "_index": indexname,
                   "_type": "doc",
                   "_source": json_line
               }

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       pb = parallel_bulk(es, insert_data("superfile.bulk.json", "contentindex"), 
                          chunk_size=10000, thread_count=16, queue_size=16)
       deque(pb, maxlen=0)
   ```

---

*Facts*

- I got a machine with *2 processors xeon 8-core* and *64GB ram*
- I tried multiple values for each `[100-50000]/[2-24]/[2-24]`

*Questions*

- Can I still improve the time ?
- If not, should I think of a way to write the data on a file and then use a process for `curl` command ?

—————————

If I try only the parse part it takes 15sec :

```
tm = time.time()
array = []

pb = insert_data("superfile.bulk.json", "contentindex") 
for p in pb:
   array.append(p)
print(time.time() - tm)            # 15

pb = parallel_bulk(es, array, chunk_size=10000, thread_count=16, queue_size=16)
dequeue(pb, maxlen = 0)
print(time.time() - tm)              # 90
```